# Array index out of range when I am inserting an element into the array

Tags: arrays, swift, append, swift3

I have an array that contains UIViews (cells) that starts empty. I set it's values when a function is fired by looping through a different array:

```
cells = [cell0, cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4]

// Code in function ↓

var cellAnimationArray: [NPFCarouselCell] = []

for cell in self.cells {
    if cell.frame == farLeftFrame {
        cellAnimationArray.insert(cell, at: 0)
    } else if cell.frame == leftFrame {
        cellAnimationArray.insert(cell, at: 1)
    } else if cell.frame == centerFrame {
        cellAnimationArray.insert(cell, at: 2)
    } else if cell.frame == rightFrame {
        cellAnimationArray.insert(cell, at: 3)
    } else if cell.frame == farRightFrame {
        cellAnimationArray.insert(cell, at: 4)
    } else {
        print("Frame does not exist!")
        print(cell.frame)
        return
}
```

When I get to the line `cellAnimationArray.insert(cell, at: 4)`, the app crashes with :

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

Why am I getting an out of index error when I am insert an item into the array?

Comment: @tktsubota. The way I am using the array I have to know which element is where. That is why I am using insert.

Comment: You can' insert at index 4 into an empty array. How will it know what to fill 0...3 with?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov. The issue is that, for example, index 3 is not assigned, so index 4 does not exist?

Comment: Using parallel arrays to store related data is really fragile and poor design anywy. I would consider architeching a new design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error message is telling you that you're calling `insert(cell, at:4)` before inserting enough elements for `4` to be a valid index. Which implies that the order of items in `self.cells` is such that you're hitting that line before the inserts at 0 through 3. But you can't insert at 4 unless there's already something at 0 through 3.

When you use an array which already contains several items, you avoid this because index 4 is already valid.